# Tower made of buckets - speeding up alghoritm

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I need to speed up my algorithm. It is about finding height of tower. Tower is build from buckets. Each bucket has height and radius (1 <= height,radius <= 1000). Variable `bucketCount` describe how many buckets are placed on tower (1 <= bucketCount <= 10<sup>6</sup>). We set buckets in sequence. Thickness of bucket is 0 (for simplicity)

Image of example tower

[image: Image of example tower]

I decided to use stack. My algorithm for each bucket:

1. If stack is empty then push bucket to stack,
2. If bucket I hold is narrower then bucket on top then put it on stack
3. Else while bucket I hold is wider: pop and find maximum height (for new bucket ground), after that push bucket which I hold.

For each bucket I added additional variable ground which specify on which height bucket is placed. Meantime I keep maximum height of tower in variable.

I guess that this while takes too much time but I can't find way to trick it. Is there any way to speed up? I used profiling and I know that `top()` takes a lot of time.

Example input: `2 20 20 30 30`
Output: 50

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

class Bucket{
public:
    int height;
    int radius;
    int ground;
};

int main()
{
    stack<Bucket> tower;
    int hightestPoint = 0;
    int bucketCount;
    cin >> bucketCount;
    Bucket temp;
    int maksimum;
    int sum;
    for(int i = 0; i < bucketCount; i++){
        cin >> temp.radius >> temp.height;
        maksimum = -1;
        sum = 0;
        if(tower.empty()){
            temp.ground = 0;
            tower.push(temp);
        } else {
            if(temp.radius < tower.top().radius){ //If bucket is narrower then push it
                temp.ground = tower.top().ground;
                tower.push(temp);
            } else { //If bucket is wider
                while(!tower.empty() && temp.radius >= tower.top().radius){ //Pop and search for new ground (maximum)
                    sum = tower.top().height + tower.top().ground;
                    if(maksimum < sum){
                        maksimum = sum;
                    }
                    tower.pop();
                }
                temp.ground = maksimum; //Set ground for new bucket
                tower.push(temp);
            }
        }
        sum = tower.top().height + tower.top().ground; //Meantime find highest point in stack
        if(hightestPoint < sum){
            hightestPoint = sum;
        }
    }
    cout << hightestPoint << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Update #1**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Bucket{
public:
    int height;
    int radius;
    int ground;
};

bool compareBuckets(Bucket a, Bucket b){
    if(a.radius > b.radius){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool compareMax(Bucket a, Bucket b){
    if((a.height + a.ground) > (b.height + b.ground)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int ile;
   // cin >> ile;
   ile = 1;
    for(int p = 0; p< ile; p++){
        vector<Bucket> tower;
        int hightestPoint = 0;
        int bucketCount;
       // cin >> bucketCount;
        bucketCount = 1000000;
        Bucket temp;
        vector<Bucket>::iterator low;
        vector<Bucket>::iterator element;
        int sum;
        for(int i = 0; i < bucketCount; i++){
            //cin >> temp.radius >> temp.height;
            temp.radius = i % 1000;
            temp.height = i % 1000;
            sum = 0;
            if(tower.empty()){
                temp.ground = 0;
                tower.push_back(temp);
            } else {
                if(temp.radius < tower.back().radius){ //If bucket is narrower then push it
                    temp.ground = tower.back().ground;
                    tower.push_back(temp);
                } else { //If bucket is wider
                    low= lower_bound (tower.begin(), tower.end(), temp,compareBuckets);
                    element = max_element(low, tower.end(), compareMax);
                    Bucket b = tower.at(element-tower.begin());
                    temp.ground = b.ground + b.height;//Set ground for new bucket
                    tower.erase(low, tower.end());
                    tower.push_back(temp);
                }
            }
            sum = tower.back().height + tower.back().ground; //Meantime find highest point in stack
            if(hightestPoint < sum){
                hightestPoint = sum;
            }
        }
        cout << hightestPoint << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't follow your explanation of the algorithm.  It appears that the first time you have a bucket wider than the previous bucket, you stop and read off the tower height.  Until then you continue to nest buckets.  Your diagram shows otherwise.

Comment: @Prune Sorry for the mistake. I changed third step. This while allow me to find new ground height for bucket which i will place on top

Comment: Your original algorithm, as described and before the update, looks fine and should be super fast.  Maybe you just need to compile in release mode.

Comment: if it works then probably it's more suitable on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As Matt pointed out, no edit is required.

The `while` statement loops through the stack and finds the bucket just wider than the new one. This is essentially finding an element in the list, just smaller than some new element. Which can be done easily using Binary search or storing the list in a set.

To implement this, you can use [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) for maintaining your stack and then [lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) to find the appropriate bucket.

Comment: I added code above in Update #1. Its filled with example input. Code using stack work on my computer in 0.4s. This code from update works around 0.4s too. In this while i searched for max too. I need it because i have to keep my ground. Did i do something wrong? Whats worse output is diffrent.

Comment: Few issues
1.  The suggestion for replacing while statement with lower_bound was to reduce the Time complexity to $\mathcal(O)\log{size\_ of\_stack}$. The max_element call takes linear time to search for the required element. Replacing that with something efficient should be helpful (A segment tree, a set, a range maxima DS)
2.  The test case you're generating is not....... elegant(?). The ```lower_bound``` call will point to the last element, which means that you're adding extra steps and not using the ability to do a binary search on the stack.
3.  Replace $>$ by $>=$ on line 15

Comment: adding a binary search changes the worst case complexity of this algorithm from O(N) to O(N log N)

Comment: The worst case complexity of the ```while``` statement was O(N) in original, making the complexity of complete code to be O(N^2). Replacing ```while``` with binary search brings it down to O(logN) for finding the infimum and O(NlogN) overall.

Comment: Each iteration of the while loop removes a bucket.  How could there possibly be O(N^2) total iterations when there are only O(N) buckets?